# How to store webcam captured image path in mysql database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I've tried the following code for capture a image, it stores image in specified folder but the path of image which i want to store in database doesn't work.The execution of code stops after Uploding... message.Please help me,whats going wrong with my code.

```js
<!--test.php-->
<?php
session_start();
include 'connection.php';
$name = date('YmdHis');
$newname=mysql_real_escape_string("images/".$name.".jpg");
$file = file_put_contents( $newname, file_get_contents('php://input') );
if (!$file) {
 print "ERROR: Failed to write data to $filename, check permissions\n";
 exit();
}
else
{
    $sql="Insert into entry(images) values('$newname')";
    $result=mysql_query($con,$sql)
            or die("Error in query");
    $value=mysql_insert_id($con);
    $_SESSION["myvalue"]=$value;
}

$url = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . dirname($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) . '/' . $newname;
print "$url\n";

?>
```

```html
<!--index.php-->
<?php
session_start();
if(isset ($_POST["send"]))
{
    $getname=$_POST["myname"];
    include 'connection.php';
    $idvalue=$_SESSION["myvalue"];
    $sql="update entry set name='$getname' where id='$idvalue'";
    $result=mysql_query($sql)
            or die(mysql_error());
    if($result)
    {
        echo "Uploaded $_SESSION[myvalue] re ..... ";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "$_SESSION[myvalue] nahi hua";
    }
}
?>

<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];?>" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="myname" id="myname">
    <input type="submit" name="send" id="send">
</form>

<script type="text/javascript" src="webcam.js"></script>
<script language="JavaScript">
  document.write( webcam.get_html(320, 240) );
</script>
<form>
  <input type=button value="Configure..." onClick="webcam.configure()">
  &nbsp;&nbsp;
  <input type=button value="Take Snapshot" onClick="take_snapshot()">
 </form>

<script language="JavaScript">
  document.write( webcam.get_html(320, 240) );
</script>

<script language="JavaScript">
    webcam.set_api_url( 'test.php' );
  webcam.set_quality( 90 ); // JPEG quality (1 - 100)
  webcam.set_shutter_sound( true ); // play shutter click sound
  webcam.set_hook( 'onComplete', 'my_completion_handler' );

  function take_snapshot(){
   // take snapshot and upload to server
   document.getElementById('upload_results').innerHTML = '<h1>Uploading...</h1>';
   webcam.snap();
  }

  function my_completion_handler(msg) {
   // extract URL out of PHP output
   if (msg.match(/(http\:\/\/\S+)/)) {
    // show JPEG image in page
    document.getElementById('upload_results').innerHTML ='<h1>Upload Successful!</h1>';
    // reset camera for another shot
    webcam.reset();
   }
   else {alert("PHP Error: " + msg);
   }
  }
 </script>
<div id="upload_results" style="background-color:#eee;"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of giving relative path in the `file_get_contents()` give full path/actual path.

Hope this might help you.

Comment: i tried but give syntaxError:malformed hexadecimal character escape sequence